# Is it possible to reduce the width of a single subplot in gridspec/Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, width, subplot

I have a grid of subplots created using gridspec. I know how to create subplots that span rows and columns in gridspec. Is it possible to reduce the width of a single sub-plot just by a small amount? For example, can we set the width ratio for a single subplot? The way I want it is marked in red in the image.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 5,  height_ratios=[0.5,1,1])

for i in range(1, 3):
    for j in range(5):
      ax = plt.subplot(gs[i, j])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,1:2])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0,2:])

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.tick_params(size=0)
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

What I tried:

I tried setting the width ratio as `width_ratios = [1,1,1,1,0.5]`, but that reduces the width of the whole column (last column).

Comment: You can always do ax.set_postion on the subplot you want to shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @JodyKlymak for mentioning about `ax.set_postion` method. @mozway provided a working solution, but adding these few lines in my code gave me the desired output:

```
bb = ax2.get_position()
bb.x1 = 0.84
ax2.set_position(bb)

bb = ax2.get_position()
bb.x0 = 0.50
ax2.set_position(bb)
```

[image]

Comment: A similar approach 
```ll, bb, ww, hh = ax2017.get_position().bounds```

```ax2017.set_position([ll, bb, ww*0.8, hh*0.8])```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GridSpec for multicolumn layouts](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_multicolumn.html). Here create a grid with 3 rows, 7 columns with width ratios [1,1,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0.5], and plot axes in the second and third rows in the combined 0.5 columns.

```
gs = GridSpec(3, 7, figure=fig, width_ratios=[1,1,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0.5])
ax_merged_top = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 3:6])
ax_row1_pseudocol3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 2:4])
```

Here is a full example:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 7, figure=fig,
                       height_ratios=[0.5,1,1],
                       width_ratios=[1,1,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0.5])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
ax_merged_top = plt.subplot(gs[0, 3:6])

for row in [1,2]:
    extra=0
    for col in range(5):
        if col in (2,4):
            ax = plt.subplot(gs[row,col+extra:col+extra+2])
            extra+=1
        else:
            ax = plt.subplot(gs[row,col+extra])
```

[image: custom gridspec]

And now you can change width_ratio to anything provided the numbers initially set as [0.5,0.5] add up to 1, example below with `width_ratios=[1,1,0.3,0.7,1,0.5,0.5]`

[image: alternative width ratio]

Comment: This changes the column width of the other sub-plots as well.